# Segment Fault using threads

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This code runs but keeps hitting a segment fault (core dumped). Not sure where the issue is is, I have tried to run it a different variables for the threads and it creates a large error while trying to run using a 2.

```
*** thread 21474836484 sees value 32
*** thread 21474836484 sees value 33
*** thread 38654705672 sees value 25
*** thread 34359738375 sees value 29
*** thread 34359738375 sees value 30
Thread 34359738375 sees final value 31
*** thread 21474836484 sees value 31
*** thread 38654705672 sees value 32
*** thread 21474836484 sees value 33
*** thread 38654705672 sees value 34
*** thread 21474836484 sees value 35
Thread 21474836484 sees final value 36
*** Error in `./treadcreator': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffeab9a33bc ***
*** thread 8589934593 sees value 29
*** thread 8589934593 sees value 30
*** thread 8589934593 sees value 31
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

struct my_thread_info {
    long which;
};

int SharedVariable = 0;

void *SimpleThread(void *data) {
    int num, val;
    struct my_thread_info *info = data;

    for (num = 0; num < 20; num++) {
        if (random() > RAND_MAX / 2)
            usleep(10);
        val = SharedVariable;
        printf("*** thread %ld sees value %d\n", info->which, val);
        SharedVariable = val + 1;
    }

    val = SharedVariable;
    printf("Thread %ld sees final value %d\n", info->which, val);

    free(info);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int j = 0, isDigit = 1;
    while (j < strlen(argv[1])) {
        isDigit = isdigit(argv[1][j]);
        if (isDigit == 0) break;
        j++;
    }
    if (isDigit == 1) {
        int num_threads = atoi(argv[1]); // Convert first argument to integer.

        pthread_t threads[num_threads];
        int args[num_threads];
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
            args[i] = i + 1;

            if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, SimpleThread, &args[i]) != 0) {
                printf("error: Cannot create thread # %d\n", i + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        int a = 0;
        for (a = 0; a < num_threads; i++)
            if (pthread_join(threads[a], NULL) != 0)
                printf("error: Cannot join thread # %d\n", a + 1);
    } else
        printf("Enter a valid number for number of threads to be created\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember to only `free` what you `malloc`. You don't `malloc` anything, so you should not `free` anything either.

Comment: Oh and you have some nasty data-races with your use of `SharedVariable`.

Comment: `valgrind` and `gdb`are your friends to find issues.

Comment: I tried removing the free command and ran into an infinite loop :(.  
After using gdb and running the program i received the following:                                   (gdb) run
Starting program: /root/threadcreator
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7960ff1 in __strlen_sse2_pminub () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-222.el7.x86_64
(gdb)

Comment: Begin with building with debug information (add the `-g` flag when building), and then GDB will be able to tell you exactly on which line in your code the crash happens.

Comment: By the way, you *do* pass an argument to the program when you run it? Maybe you should add a check for that? E.g. `if (argc < 2) { printf("To few arguments\n"); return 1; }`

Comment: Thank you, i removed the free  and changed my code to the following which worked,   void* SimpleThread(void *which)

Answer (score 1):

In general, any crash inside `malloc` or `free` (in this case, `munmap_chunk` is called by `free`) is very likely to be the result of heap corruption.

In this particular case, you `free(info)`, but you didn't `malloc` it (`info` points to stack variable `args[i]`).

Freeing un-allocated memory is one specific instance of heap corruption. Other causes: `free`ing something twice, overflowing `malloc`ed buffer, etc. etc.

A nice way to find this (and similar) bugs is by running the program under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or (better) [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for your help, i changed my code to the following below, which worked out and did not cause any error codes. I removed the free and added a break which was causing an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>


int SharedVariable = 0;

void* SimpleThread(void *which) 
{
int num, val = 0;

for(num = 0; num < 20; num++) 
{
if (random() > RAND_MAX / 2)
usleep(10);

val = SharedVariable;

printf("*** thread %d sees value %d\n", which, val);             
SharedVariable = val + 1;

}

val = SharedVariable;

printf("Thread %d sees final value %d\n", which, val);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int j = 0, isDigit = 1;
while (j < strlen(argv[1])) 
{
    isDigit = isdigit(argv[1][j]);
    if (isDigit == 0) break;
    j++;
}
if (isDigit == 1)
{
    int num_threads = atoi(argv[1]); // Convert first         
argument to integer.

    pthread_t threads[num_threads];
    int args[num_threads];
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)

    {
        args[i] = i + 1;

        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, 
  SimpleThread, &args[i]) != 0)

        {
            printf("error: Cannot create thread # 
   %d\n", i + 1);
            break;

        }
    }
    int a = 0;
    for (a = 0; a < num_threads; i++)

        if (pthread_join(threads[a], NULL) != 0)
        {
            printf("error: Cannot join thread # %d\n", 
    a + 1);
            break;
        }


  }
  else
    printf("Enter a valid number for number of threads 
 to be created\n");
 return 0;
}
```